# Imagemagick: apply cutout-region to another image

Tags: imagemagick

I have an PNG image with a transparent background, but the content is opaque. The transparent section is a mask that I would like to apply to another PNG image, so that they have identical transparent sections but may differ in the opaque section.

I have tried

```
convert mask.png image.png -composite mask.png -compose copyopacity -composite image.png
```

but that seems to alter the opaque section in image.png.

Answer (score 2):

In Imagemagick, assuming the two images are the same size, then try

(Unix syntax)

```
convert \
opaque_image.png \
\( transparent_image.png -alpha extract \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
result.png
```

(Windows syntax)

```
convert ^
opaque_image.png ^
( transparent_image.png -alpha extract ) ^
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite ^
result.png
```

It is possible that your transparent image does not have a binary alpha channel. For example, the alpha values may be 0 (fully transparent) in the areas you want to discard, but may be say only 80% in the areas you want to preserve. In that case, it will modify the opaque regions you want to preserve. One solution would be the threshold the mask before applying it to the opaque image.

Comment: Thanks for a good reply! This answer led me to further findings. You are correct that I need to use a threshold as the transparent image has a non-binary alpha channel. However, I noticed that opaque_image also has a non-binary alpha channel (bad naming). I would like to leave the alpha-channel inside the white mask region, while setting alpha to 0 in the black region.

Comment: You will need to extract both alpha channels, the multiply them together, then add that result as a new alpha channel to the opaque image. If you do not know how to do that, then post your two images and I will show you the commands. To multiply two images, you can use `-compose multiply -composite` or `-evaluate-sequence multiply`.